# Firebase not fetching all data all the times

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

**The Code**

I have the following code to populate a ViewHolder

```
@Override
            protected void populateViewHolder(RankingViewHolder viewHolder, final Ranking model, int position) {
                final Context mContext = getActivity().getApplicationContext();

                viewHolder.txt_name.setText(model.getUserName());
                viewHolder.txt_score.setText(String.valueOf(model.getScore()));
                viewHolder.txt_class.setText(model.getUser_class());
                Picasso.with(mContext).load(model.getAvatarUrl()).error(R.drawable.ic_people_black_24dp).into(viewHolder.personPhoto);


                viewHolder.setItemClickListener(new ItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view, int position, boolean isLongClick) {
                        Intent scoreDetail = new Intent(getActivity(), ScoreDetail.class);
                        scoreDetail.putExtra("viewUser", model.getUserName());
                        startActivity(scoreDetail);

                    }
                });

            }
        };
```

The RankingViewHolder code is:

```
public class RankingViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

    private ItemClickListener itemClickListener;

    public TextView txt_name, txt_score, txt_class;

    public ImageView personPhoto;

    public RankingViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        txt_name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_name);
        txt_score = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_score);
        personPhoto = itemView.findViewById(R.id.person_photo);
        txt_class = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_class);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    public void setItemClickListener(ItemClickListener itemClickListener) {
        this.itemClickListener = itemClickListener;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        itemClickListener.onClick(view , getAdapterPosition(),false);

    }
}
```

**The Problem:**

Code works fine BUT for some reason sometimes i get all data, sometimes no picture, or no class_text. The data come from firebase, so as my code works i guess its something has to do with Firebase.

Is there any way to get all the data i need? If additional code needed pls ask, but if was code problem, it shouldnt work at all. [image]

**Additional Info as asked**

Ranking Model

```
public class Ranking {

    private String userName;
    private long score;
    private String avatarUrl;
    private String user_class;

    public Ranking(String userName, long score, String avatarUrl, String user_class) {
        this.userName = userName;
        this.score = score;
        this.avatarUrl = avatarUrl;
        this.user_class = user_class;
    }

    public Ranking() {

    }

    public Ranking(String userName, long score) {
        this.userName = userName;
        this.score = score;
    }

    public Ranking(String userName, long score, String avatarUrl) {
        this.userName = userName;
        this.score = score;
        this.avatarUrl = avatarUrl;
    }

    public String getUser_class() {
        return user_class;
    }

    public void setUser_class(String user_class) {
        this.user_class = user_class;
    }

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    public long getScore() {
        return score;
    }

    public void setScore(long score) {
        this.score = score;
    }

    public String getAvatarUrl() {
        return avatarUrl;
    }

    public void setAvatarUrl(String avatarUrl) {
        this.avatarUrl = avatarUrl;
    }
}
```

Firebase Structure:

```
"anny" : {
      "avatar" : "https://i.imgur.com/5dwlAI2.png",
      "avatarUrl" : "https://i.imgur.com/5dwlAI2.png",
      "score" : 470,
      "userName" : "anny",
      "user_class" : "Geography"
    },
```

Comment: can you post your database structure and also your Ranking model ?

Comment: Try using keepSynced for the firebase reference if not using already.

Comment: I tried it but still the same. As the code works i guess its firebase problem, so i ll try to remove any listeners or anything that make the getting data slower.